# Custom HTML in wordpress does not allow empty Span class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using Thrive Builder in wordpress and I am using Custom HTML.

Whenever I add 
 an Empty span

the search icon will appear first in preview, but then after I refresh the page and check it in live page the span class disappear.

Already Tried this function

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
$opts = '*[*]';
$initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
$initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
return $initArray;
} 
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

But I am just getting a PHP error, maybe because I am just using Custom HTML. I am not using plugin for this. 
Any Idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
  $opts = '*[id|name|class|style]';
  $initArray['valid_elements'] .= ',' . $opts;
  $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $opts;
  return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```